# dokuwiki docsearch plugin has strange behaviour

Tags: php, search, cron, file-permissions, dokuwiki

closest thread about my problem is this one https://forum.dokuwiki.org/thread/7349

Although it seems that the solution from that thread is already incorporated into current version of docseach, I still have this problem. My setup is Ubuntu 12.04, with stock Apache2 and php5; safe_mode is off. I checked permissions as well. Everything is fine.

I'm trying the script by:

```
su www-data
php cron.php
```

My results are very inconsistent. Before last trial, there were extracted txt files in pages directory, but in my last trial there is nothing.

Thank you very much!

Update:

I ran this script once more, from command line, as www-data user. And this is an output

```
$ php5 cron.php
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/w26.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/i20.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/w20.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123

PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/i11.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/metadata.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/i18.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/w1.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/w30.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/i22.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/i16.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/index/pageword.idx): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123

PHP Warning:  rmdir(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/pages): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 140
PHP Warning:  rmdir(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/locks): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 140
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/cache/0/0946805efd851f13ce467298dd1151b4.metadata): Permission denied in /home/www-data/www/hj/lib/plugins/docsearch/cron.php on line 123
PHP Warning:  unlink(/home/www-data/www/hj/./data/docsearch/cache/0/0946805
```

So, as a result I got four folders, and only **pages** folder included txt files extracted from doc and pdf. Index folder was empty.

The strange thing was that all four service folders become root user and root group. It seems, although I run the `php cron.php` as www-data user, somewhere root user is interferes. Actually, per [plugin](https://www.dokuwiki.org/plugin%3adocsearch) page I need to set up a cron job, I did that as well.

Next time again, when I run php cron.php, -- nothing, not even folders.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, the main problem was that I used `crontab -e` being a root. So when cron job run, it  rendered plugin directory unwritable to www-data user (web server user).

But problem is eliminated by adding the cron job as www-data user:
`crontab -u www-data -e`.